# Spring REST controller issue in binding value of some model fields

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Rest Controller in my Web project which is running in Tomcat 8

My json request is-

```
{
    "type": "Criteria",
    "fTypeOne": "DataSource",
}
```

and my model class is

```
public class FormulaModel implements Serializable{
   private String fTypeOne;
   private String type;
}
```

When I send a json request to the rest controller from postman, I observe that the value of **fTypeOne** is not bound but **type** is bound properly.

Any help on this issue will be more than welcome.

**Environment**:

- Spring-web-4.3.14-Release
- jackson-databind-2.8.10
- Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
- Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre
- Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
- OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Could you rename fTypeOne to ftypeOne ? maybe it can work like that..

Comment: Yes , now its working fine when i rename the field name "fTypeOne" to "ftypeOne"

Comment: Thanks, can you explain this why "fTypeOne" is not binding

Answer (score 0):

"fTypeOne": "DataSource"**,**

please remove the ',' at last and try.

Comment: yes i will try this also  , by removing  the ','  but not solve the issues

Comment: can you please share more details on the error you getting.
paste the error message here.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the automatic mappers to work you need to declare the following things:

1. Empty Constructor
2. Getter and Setter

Please check if you have the following elements in your code:

```
private String fTypeOne;

public void setFTypeOne(String fTypeOne) {
   this.fTypeOne = fTypeOne;
}

public String getFTypeOne() {
   return this.fTypeOne;
}
```

Comment: Yes I did , but issues not solved, When I renamed the field "fTypeOne" to "ftypeOne" its working, but why "fTypeOne" is not binding can any one explain ??

Comment: Please note that the Setter and getter names must be exactly the same as the ones above. The mappers are case sensitive so since you chose a getter for the field fTypeOne(Capital T and Capital O) the Setter and Getter must have a Capital T and a Capital O

Comment: i am using   @Getter and Setter for generate getter and setter so when I change field name ,I  think  no need to worry about mappers.